# Как сделать рассылку на пхп для 100к получателей

Tags: php, email

есть такая проблема - хочу создать скрипт рассылок подписчикам а их потенциально может быть до 100 000 
но тут два непонятных момента 1 если написать тупо скрипт который берет записи из бд и оптравляет каждому письмо то ведь так долго скрипт не отработает, 2 хостеры ставят лимит в нескольо тысяч писем в сутки, и пишут что все хостеры так делают, если все хостеры так делают то как почти все развитые сайты расылают огромное количество писем всем пользователям? например фриланс сайты, тот же майл ру, фотострана, темфорест и море других сайтов, кто имееет опыт в создании таких расылок очень прошу помогите советом

Comment: Если интерестно как делаются Очень большие рассылки (перечисленные mail.ru, фотострана) то тут есть [доклад Андрея Саса](http://www.slideshare.net/AndreySas/100-badoo) о там как такие рассылки делаются в Badoo.

Comment: Как быстро хотите разослать письма? Будете обходить ограничения хостера? Или есть возможность поднять собственный сервер и организовать там очереди?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется возможны два варианта:

- Поднять свой сервер приложений и закидывать туда задачи по рассылке пачкек писем.
- Использовать сервис отправки email.

Проблемы:

- В первом случае - вы столкнетёсь с инфраструктурой в которой работает ваше приложение. Ограничение хостера на исходящие письма, отсутствие возможности поднять свой демон, сложности в администрировании, разработке и т.д.
- Второй вариант в большинстве кейсов ставит лимит по количеству в день/месяц, скорее всего платный, но при этом не нужно админить.

Тут уже вопрос к вам, какой вариант более приемлем.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 если написать тупо скрипт который берет записи из бд и оптравляет каждому письмо то ведь так долго скрипт не отработает

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',86400 /*1 day*/);
```

> 2 хостеры ставят лимит в нескольо тысяч писем в сутки, и пишут что все хостеры так делают, если все хостеры так делают то как почти все развитые сайты расылают огромное количество писем всем пользователям?

У развитых сайтов свои собственные сервера, хостеров они только как облако используют - что-то раз в день вычислить, сделать бекапы. И менее развитые сайты никто не ограничивает - если хостинг тебе даёт виртуалку: делай что хочешь, правь что хочешь под рутом, настраивай рассылку почты, подписывай. Пример такого хостинга firstvds.ru